# Unable to pull elasticsearch and kibana using docker-compose in RHEL 7 server

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose

Unable to pull Elasticsearch and Kibana images by using docker compose.

When I was trying to retry muliple times using docker-compose up cmd, each and every time some of the service are not available, which is unpredictable.

Can somebody please guide me what causing the issue, even the proxy has been set in docker.service.

Please find the attached screenshot, I have also given the docker-compose.yaml file for reference.

Kindly let me know in case of any further information needed.

[image]

**Docker-compose.yml File**

```
    version: '2.2'

services:

  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.8.0
    container_name: elasticsearch
    environment:
      - node.name=elasticsearch
      - discovery.seed_hosts=elasticsearch
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=elasticsearch
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - esdata1:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200

  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.8.0
    container_name: kibana
    environment:
      ELASTICSEARCH_URL: "http://elasticsearch:9200"
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch

volumes:
  esdata1:
    driver: local
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was issue with RHEL server trying with multiple times the issue got solved